# How to make ( \section ) flushleft like on article or report?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, amsart

I'm using `\docummentclass{amsart}`and when using `\section` it prints it out in the center of the line how to make it on left I used `\begin{flushleft} \section \end{flushlef}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `\centering` from the definition of `\section` using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch. Since the patch would be permanent from that point forward, you can save the original and modified definitions and creates switches to change the style on demand:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\let\centeredsection\section% Copy original centered definition of \section

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\section}{\centering}{}{}{}

\let\flushleftsection\section% Copy updated non-centered definition of \section
\newcommand{\sectionscenter}{\let\section\centeredsection}% Switch to centered \section
\newcommand{\sectionsleft}{\let\section\flushleftsection}% Switch to flush left \section

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\section{A section}% Flush left

\sectionscenter

\section{Another section}% Centered

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: i removed the '\centering' but it didn't work but i replaced it by putting '\flushleft' in the third brackets and it worked. thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately it made the 'bibliography' shifted to the left too ( I didn't know it is treated as a section) how to make it in the center again. Thank you again.

Comment: @mostafax80: See my updated answer which provides switches to change the style of the section on demand.